# Getting nodes by unique ID with angularFire (v2)

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have a simple problem that I seem to be struggling with. I'm building a simple workout tracker, and I'm trying to add workouts. I'm defining the unique IDs for the workouts by using `Date.now()`, and something something like this:

```
  // get the overall ref to the Firebase
  $scope.workouts = $firebase(new Firebase("https://robus.firebaseio.com/workouts"));

  $scope.addWorkout = function() {    
    var newWorkout = $firebase(new Firebase("https://robus.firebaseio.com/workouts/" + id));
    newWorkout.$set({
      id: Date.now();,
      name: this.workoutName,
    });

    this.workoutName = "";
  },
```

This works. I get nodes in my Firebase tree that look like:

[http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68704/Screenshots/xrev.png http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68704/Screenshots/xrev.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68704/Screenshots/xrev.png)

Although this seems a little redundant to me. I'm storing the `id` because I can't figure out how to "get" the node otherwise. Do I have to use `$child`? I've tried things like:

`console.log(newWorkout.$child('1386976952038'));` and I always get `TypeError: Cannot call method 'ref' of undefined` errors.

Comment: Hi - are you sure you're using the latest version of angularfire.js 0.5.0 (eg, from: https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.js)? We fixed a bug with $child sometime ago - it's definitely the right way to do what you want.

Comment: I am also struggling with V2, particularly related to any interaction with $child or $save. Another similar issue is also referenced in a SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578726/getting-key-values-in-angularfire-v2. Using 0.5.0 latest version. @Anant is there a more in depth app example making full use of the new API?

Comment: So I did a diff on my 0.5.0 code (via Bower) and the latest on Github and saw that the latest fix https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/commit/0fd5e35348a5efafa9f8860f5904d2923eddf386 is not in my 0.5.0 version. Replacing that in my project fixed the 'ref' error thanks.