# Getting key values in AngularFire v2

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to get the priority of the last loaded item, but I'm having a hard time with Version 2:

```
 $scope.items = $firebase(new Firebase("https://***.firebaseio.com/"));

 $scope.items.$on('loaded', function() { 

  console.log($scope.items.$child(".priority"));

 });

});
```

That gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ref' of undefined
```

Am I getting close?

Comment: There was a fix for this particular error recently:  https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/commit/0fd5e35348a5efafa9f8860f5904d2923eddf386. Updating to this version fixed an issue similar to yours on my codebase. Whats your version?

Comment: Nope, I just updated but it's still giving me that error.

Comment: Another issue possibly related: the example in the docs for $getIndex - http://angularfire.com/flatdoc.html#getindex returns "undefined"

Comment: Wait - it is working, or at least it's giving me a different error now.

Comment: What's the error you're getting now?